# How to get matched rows from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am not able to get a correct response and getting the same response multiple times

anything that I get multiple matching results and also I posted my response like that I need

I tried so many ways but not getting a response

I ended this much code

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

        // include db details
        include_once('include/conn.php');
        header("Content-type: application/json");

        /* ----- Get Request Method, Path Info, Input JSON ----- */
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $reqInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
        } else {

        }

        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->getConnection();

        $resOutput = array();
        $resOutput2 = array();

        try {

        $lclQuery1 = "
SELECT el_id as id
     , el_title as title
     , el_start_date as startDate
     , el_end_date as endDate
     , el_status 
  FROM election 
 WHERE el_status = 0 
   AND el_election_status = 2 
 GROUP 
    BY title
";
        $qryResult1 =  $db->query($lclQuery1);

        $lclQuery2 = "
SELECT em_id as id1
     , em_el_id AS emID
     , em_party_name AS partyName
     , em_party_image AS partyImage
     , em_total_seat AS totalSeat
     , em_lost_seat AS lostSeat
     , em_won_seat AS wonSeat
     , em_pending_seat AS pendingSeat
     , em_status 
  FROM election_mul 
 WHERE em_status = 0
";
        $qryResult2 =  $db->query($lclQuery2);

        if($qryResult1->rowCount() > 0) {

                $resOutput["status"] = 1;
                $resOutput["msg"] = "election";

            while($row1 = $qryResult1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $resOutput1["desc"] = $row1;

                // var_dump($row1);

                while($row2 = $qryResult2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                    if($row1['id'] == $row2['emID']) {

                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['id1'] =  $row2["id1"];
                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['partyName'] = $row2["partyName"];
                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['partyImage'] =  $row2["partyImage"];
                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['totalSeat'] = $row2["totalSeat"];
                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['lostSeat'] = $row2["lostSeat"];
                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['wonSeat'] = $row2["wonSeat"];
                        $resOutput2[$row2["id1"]]['pendingSeat'] = $row2["pendingSeat"];
                        
                    }
                }

                $resOutput1["election"] = array_values($resOutput2);
                $resOutput["election1"] = $resOutput1;
                // $resOutput["election1"] = $resOutput3;

                // $db = null;
                
                // echo $Encryption->encrypt($encrypted, $lclAppKey);
            }
            echo $encrypted = json_encode($resOutput);

        } else {

            $resOutput["status"] = 0;
            $resOutput["msg"] = "No Records";
            $db = null;
            echo $encrypted = json_encode($resOutput);
            // echo $Encryption->encrypt($encrypted, $lclAppKey);

        }

            $db = null;
            echo $encrypted = json_encode($resOutput);
             // $Encryption->encrypt($encrypted, $lclAppKey);
        }
    // }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

?>

```
I want to get like this Response


{
  "status": 1,
  "msg": "election",
  "election1": {
    "desc": {
    "id": "17",
    "title": "fsdf",
    "startDate": "2020-11-24",
    "endDate": "2020-11-26",
    "el_status": "0"
  },
  "election": [
    {
    "id1": "21",
    "partyName": "ggg",
    "partyImage": "../upimg/election/25-0.jpg",
    "totalSeat": "22",
    "lostSeat": "2",
    "wonSeat": "33",
    "pendingSeat": "1"
  },
  {
    "id1": "22",
    "partyName": "uytr",
    "partyImage": "../upimg/election/25-1.jpg",
    "totalSeat": "22",
    "lostSeat": "2",
    "wonSeat": "33",
    "pendingSeat": "1"
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: I want to do in mysql itself

Comment: Will you update my code??

Comment: What is your question?? And where is your table schema??